# Dialog is Displaying Twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-dialogfragment

I am using View Model Architecture, which is having different states.
One of the state is use to show a dialog.
So once a dialog is shown and if I close the app for sometimes and opens it again the system creates the previous dialog and since the Fragment is created again the View Model State is creating the dialog again.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to clear the state in your view model each time you show a dialog, so directly after showing the dialog in your fragment clear the state of showing a dialog in your view model.

Comment: But then if I click on any buttons in my dialog fragment it says fragment not attached to a context 
It is a custom dialog fragment

Comment: @Target can you add some code so I can understand the issue, because the state in your view model doesn't have nothing to do with attaching the dialog to your fragment